# angularUI ui-grid grouping feature missing?

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using `angularUI`'s new directive ([uiGrid](http://ui-grid.info/)) after they announced that it a replacement for the old one ([ngGrid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)).

it's pretty awesome but I can't find the **grouping** feature, although mentioned in their [home page](http://ui-grid.info/) under `Advanced Features`.

Am I missing something? Is there a way for me to have grouping feature in this component?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like this feature has been requested, but not yet implemented. This [github-issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/935) says it's not gonna be in november. Hopefully next month

Answer (score 4):

*as 15.6.15*

[SimpleGrouping](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping)

[Complex Grouping](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/320_complex_grouping)